# What is the more efficient way to find row-wise sum in power bi DAX?

Tags: powerbi, sum, row, dax

I have a sample table with the following values:

```
location | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
------------------------------------------
usa1     | 1    | 1    |  1   | 1       
usa2     | 1    | 0    |  1   | 1
```

values are boolean for true (1) and false (0).

I would like to add a new column that shows the sum per row. from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sum-multiple-column-using-dax-in-power-bi/

it suggested the following approach:

```
Measure Total = SUM(table[col1]) + SUM(table[col2]) + ... + SUM(table[colx])
```

I am getting the expected sum for the four columns I tried. But if I have 20 columns, I was hoping you can guide me to write the DAX more efficiently.

expected output

```
location | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | sum
------------------------------------------
usa1     | 1    | 1    |  1   | 1    | 4
usa2     | 1    | 0    |  1   | 1    | 3
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use unpivoting feature of PowerQuery to go from wide to long by selecting location and unpivot all other columns.
[image]
Then the sum by location would be immediate in any visual, no need for DAX.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way I do it is

```
Sum = table[col1] + table[col2] + table[col3] + ...
```

I am not sure if there is another way for your situation since I only had at most 5 columns to add.